# Create Invisible Window in GTK#?

Tags: c#, mono, window, x11, gtk#

I'm looking to create an invisible window for the processing of certain X events (sort of like `NativeWindow` in Winforms).  Is this possible in GTK#? Or do I need to manually create such a window using P/Invoke to the X libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand what you're trying to do, but `Window`s in Gtk are invisible by default. If you never set the visibility to true:

```
window.Visible = true;
```

or if you explicitly set it to false:

```
window.Visible = false;
```

it will remain invisible.

**Edit: This is the real solution to Zach's problem:**

> I just checked the GTK source code, and you can call Realize() on a GTK Window to make the GTK window create its corresponding GDK Window. The GDK Window is immediately hooked into the X server when it is created.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  Is there anything I need to do to make sure the `Window` is connected to the X server, while still having the `Window` invisible?

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't really know anything about X itself. You might find a better answer on the gtk-sharp-list mailing list (http://lists.ximian.com/mailman/listinfo/gtk-sharp-list).

Comment: I just checked the GTK source code, and you can call `Realize()` on a GTK Window to make the GTK window create its corresponding GDK Window.  The GDK Window is immediately hooked into the X server when it is created.

Answer (score 0):

There is also Gtk.Invisible class which is used for capturing events.